# javascript validation of space and empty field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, onsen-ui

i want to validate my form if the user type white space aur leave the field empty..

the problem is that this code word perfect when i put space in textbox and show validation..but when the space is empty it redirect to the next page

this is my controller

```
 $scope.valid=  function (){
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var contact = $("#contact").val();


        if( fname.indexOf(" ") !== -1)
        {
            $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";registermodal.show();
        }
        else if( lname.indexOf(" ") !== -1){
            $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";registermodal.show();
        }
        else if( lname.indexOf(" ") !== -1){
            $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";registermodal.show();
        }
        else if( contact.indexOf(" ") !== -1){
            $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";registermodal.show();
        }
    }
```

this is my resigter.html

```
   <ons-row style="margin-top:45px;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div>
                    <input class="textbox" id="fname" name="fname"     ng-model="fname" type="text" placeholder="First name" ng-trim='false' required/>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-top:15px;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div>
                    <input class="textbox" id="lname" ng-model="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last name" required/>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-top:15px;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div>
                    <input class="textbox" id="email" ng-model="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-top: 15px;font-family:mai;font-size: 1.2em;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div class="">
                    <span style="padding: 10px">
                        <input id="radio1" type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1">Male</label>
                    </span>
                    <span style="padding: 10px">
                        <input id="radio1" type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="2" ><label for="radio1">Female</label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
        <ons-row style="margin-top:15px;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div>
                    <input class="textbox" ng-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>

        <ons-row style="margin-top:15px;text-align: center">
            <ons-col>
                <div>
                    <input class="textbox" id="contact" ng-model="contact" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" required/>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>

        <ons-row style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px">
            <ons-col>
                <input type="button" class="loginbutton buttoncolor" value="Register" ng-click="register() ; valid()" />
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>

    <ons-row>
        <ons-modal var="registermodal">
            <div>{{modalvalue}}</div>
            <ons-button ng-click="showlogin1()" style="margin:20px;">Close</ons-button>
        </ons-modal>
    </ons-row>
```

Comment: Check for an empty string `""`. But ... no spaces allowed in a First Name ("Mary Ann") or Last Name ("Van Buren")? Better use a regex to test for any sequence of spaces (including zero),

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try this simple approche :

```
if( fname!= "" && fname!= " ")
    {
        $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";registermodal.show();
    }
```

and do the same for the others textField

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` in javascript

```
if(!fname || fname.trim() == ""){
   $scope.modalvalue = "Spaces are not allowed";
   registermodal.show();
}
...
```